# How to check device is Online or Offline Phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, offline

What is the easiest way to check whether the device(smartphone) is online or offline. 
I'm working with phonegap, jquery mobile. 
I found this one.

```
document.addEventListener("online", yourCallbackFunction, false);
```

What I want to do is to check the Internet connection and decide about to get the data from the internet or from the device local database.

```
if(deviceoffline)
  getDataFromLokalDatabase();
else
  getDataFromInternet();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`navigator.onLine`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.navigator.onLine):

```
var isOffline = 'onLine' in navigator && !navigator.onLine;

if ( isOffline ) {
    //local db
}
else {
    // internet data
}
```

But be aware of that if `navigator.onLine` isn't supported `isOffline` will always be false

Comment: Okay I test it normal on chrome browser and get only false. But i build the app with phonegap and test it on my smartphone and it works.  Thanks NULL. U helped me a lot :)

Comment: navigator.onLine does not work reliable, at least not in my PhoneGapp app (Nexus 4 with Android 5); navigator.onLine is a supported attribute though. I also found this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283124/navigator-online-not-always-working.

Answer (score 12):

This is the code using native phonegap code:

```
function checkInternet() {

    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

    if(networkState == Connection.NONE) {

        onConnexionError();
        return false;

    } else {

       return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: you should check for  `Connection.UNKNOWN` as well

Answer (score 2):

Using Jquery make a ajax call and check the error code, If you get error code as 0 the device is offline

```
$.ajax({
    //your ajax options
    error: function (request) { 
         if (request.status == 0) {
            alert("you're offline");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Status 0 means the server is not responding to the request.  That *might* be because the device is offline, but does not necessarily mean that it is.

Comment: however - in the majority of cases what you care about is whether or not your app can communicate with your server... so this is relevant!

Answer (score 1):

Beware, while navigator.onLine is the simplest solution, **it does not behave consistently on all browsers**. On Chrome it will tell you that it is online if you have a LAN cable in, even if you have no internet.

You can use the cordova plugin [network-information](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information)

You can also try to make an AJAX request to your server; usually you want to know if you are offline because in that case *you cannot communicate with the server*, so "offline" often means "not able to communicate with the server" (which can be also caused by your server being offline). Playing with timeouts or several requests is also useful if you need to check bandwidth or link quality.

Offline does not mean the same for every use case, you first need to know which of the above techniques is best suited for you, then implement one or several of them.

> What I want to do is to check the Internet connection and decide about to get the data from the internet or from the device local database.

It seems that checking the link with your server through a request is the best option for you.

Answer (score 0):

the native onLine is somewhat shaky, especially in an web app environment.. but can be used for an initial check upon pageLoad, however it is somewhat useless then as if you get to that point you have an internet connection.

attempting to ajax something is far more reliable.