# Checking device is connected to internet or not with jquery/javascript on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, jquery-mobile

Here is my code. As soon as page loaded(it is offline app).

1. Connected then link bgcolor green.
2. Not connected then link bgcolor turns red.
   It not working but.

   ```
   <script src="plugins/jqm/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
   <script src="plugins/jqm/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <style>
   .connected{ background-color:green;}
   .diconnected{background-color:red;}
   #link1{
       width: 100px;
       height: 200px;
       border: #0FF 1px solid;
   }
   </style>
   <body onLoad="checkconnection()">
   <a href="#" id="link1"><img src="images/network.png"> My status</a>

   </body>

   <script type="text/javascript">
   function checkconnection() {
   var status = navigator.onLine;
   if (status) {
   $("#link1").removeClass('diconnected').addClass('connected');
   } else {
   $("#link1").removeClass('connected').addClass('diconnected');
   }
   }
   </script>
   </html>
   ```

   Thanks in advance.

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that `navigator.onLine` represents what you think it represents, and is supported in the browser you are using? See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283124/navigator-online-not-always-working