# Code should close popup

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im trying to do a simple thing in angular js app: this is in the body in the index.html:

```
<div id="no-connection" class="alert popup-animation" data-ng-include="'modules/game/common/popups/no-connection-popup.client.view.html'" style="display:none"></div>
```

I want to hide or show it according to this: (if there is a connection or not)

var noConnectPopup = document.getElementById('no-connection');

```
  if (navigator.onLine) {
        alert('its online');
        noConnectPopup.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        alert('its offline');
        noConnectPopup.style.display = 'block';
    }

    window.addEventListener("offline", function(e) {
        alert('its ofline again');
        noConnectPopup.style.display = 'block'; //not working
    }, false);

    window.addEventListener("online", function(e) {
        alert('its online again');
        noConnectPopup.style.display = 'none'; //not working
    }, false);
```

Why the popup is not responding to the change in the dom? is it a digest/apply issue?

if yes than why? im outside of angular borders.

Comment: Do you see any errors in your console.. It is hard to understand the problem there could be many reasons why it is not working. One obvious one could be that `noConnectPopup` variable is null..

Comment: i see the alerts, i even see the dom is captured....

Comment: I *believe* `ng-include` replaces the element, so the cached element is no longer in the DOM. Try putting the `ng-include` in a div that is child of the one with id="no-connection".

Comment: Have you tried putting static content in the pop-up? Since your event handlers seem to get triggered, maybe the problem is not with the pop-up but with its dynamic content (from the ng-include)

Comment: Ooh, what @NikosParaskevopoulos said!

Comment: navigator.onLine is not trustable. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283124/navigator-online-not-always-working