# how to check Internet connection is have or not and if don't have how to show internet not connect in the popup using jquery in worklight

Tags: jquery, popup, ibm-mobilefirst, internet-connection

when **application lunch** or any **functionality invoke using internet** in that time **i want to check internet is connected or not**, so i want to show the if **internet connection not connected in the popup** how to do that in **worklight** **hybrid mobile application** using **jquery mobile**.

Please any one tell me how do that and any one have sample please put it in this question.

i write below code.

```js
//main.js

var busyIndicator=null;

function wlCommonInit(){
 
 busyIndicator = new WL.BusyIndicator('page', {text : 'Please Wait...'},{minDuration: '1s'},{color: "red"});
 
 isOnline();
}



function isOnline() {
    var online = navigator.onLine;    // Detecting the internet connection
    if(online) {
     alert('You\'re online now...');
    } else {
       alert('You\'re Offline now...');
      
      $("#errorPopup").popup("open");
    }
}
```

```html
<!--index.html -->

<div data-role="page" id="page">
       <div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px">
        <input type="text" id="txtTrtDtPreAprvlSubn" 
    placeholder="Treatment Date" required="required" autocomplete="off"
    spellcheck="false" readonly="readonly">
       </div>

 </div>


<div data-role="popup" id="errorPopup" data-overlay-theme="b"
   data-theme="b" data-corners="false" align="center">
   <p>internet connection not connected</p>
</div>
```

Comment: try with this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283124/navigator-online-not-always-working

Answer (score 0):

first of all . you can be find this answer easily.however,you can achieve the flowing API [WL.Device.getNetworkInfo](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Device.html%23getNetworkInfo) .check for Internet connection on application startup and do actions based on the result.

```
function wlCommonInit() {
    WL.Device.getNetworkInfo(function (networkInfo) {
        alert (networkInfo.isNetworkConnected);
        if (networkInfo.isNetworkConnected) { // if true, then
            // connect to the Worklight Server or do something else...
        }
    });
```

you can also check this slide http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/05_04_Working_offline.pdf