# Best practices for detecting offline state in a service worker

Tags: javascript, offline, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have a service worker that is supposed to cache an `offline.html` page that is displayed if the client has no network connection. However, it sometimes believes the navigator is offline even when it is not. That is, `navigator.onLine === false`. This means the user may get `offline.html` instead of the actual content even when online, which is obviously something I'd like to avoid.

This is how I register the service worker in my `main.js`:

```
// Install service worker for offline use and caching
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js', {scope: '/'});
}
```

My current `service-worker.js`:

```
const OFFLINE_URL = '/mysite/offline';
const CACHE_NAME = 'mysite-static-v1';

self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
  event.waitUntil(
    // Cache the offline page when installing the service worker
    fetch(OFFLINE_URL, { credentials: 'include' }).then(response =>
      caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(cache => cache.put(OFFLINE_URL, response)),
    ),
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  const requestURL = new URL(event.request.url);

  if (requestURL.origin === location.origin) {
    // Load static assets from cache if network is down
    if (/\.(css|js|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|svg)$/.test(requestURL.pathname)) {
      event.respondWith(
        caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(cache =>
          caches.match(event.request).then((result) => {
            if (navigator.onLine === false) {
              // We are offline so return the cached version immediately, null or not.
              return result;
            }
            // We are online so let's run the request to make sure our content
            // is up-to-date.
            return fetch(event.request).then((response) => {
              // Save the result to cache for later use.
              cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
              return response;
            });
          }),
        ),
      );
      return;
    }
  }

  if (event.request.mode === 'navigate' && navigator.onLine === false) {
    // Uh-oh, we navigated to a page while offline. Let's show our default page.
    event.respondWith(caches.match(OFFLINE_URL));
    return;
  }

  // Passthrough for everything else
  event.respondWith(fetch(event.request));
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried playing with ononline and onoffline? Might help you find the source... But from what we see everywhere, I'd suggest you use another mechanic to know if you should server your offline version. One of the reason is, while your user is online this doesn't mean your server is reachable/online.

Comment: Could it be related to -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283124/navigator-online-not-always-working   If so, it looks like the best way to see if online, is a background task that does and intermittent ajax call or similiar, maybe a better option might even be a websocket to your server,  so you could trust this more than the navigator.onLine..

Comment: @Keith, could be related although it's the other way around in that question. I'll check if the ajax request solves the problem.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`navigator.onLine` and the related events can be useful when you want to update your UI to indicate that you're offline and, for instance, only show content that exists in a cache.

But I'd avoid writing service worker logic that relies on checking `navigator.onLine`. Instead, attempt to make a `fetch()` unconditionally, and if it fails, provide a backup response. This will ensure that your web app behaves as expected regardless of whether the `fetch()` fails due to being offline, due to [lie-fi](https://www.outsystems.com/blog/lie-fi.html), or due to your web server experiencing issues.

```
// Other fetch handler code...

if (event.request.mode === 'navigate') {
  return event.respondWith(
    fetch(event.request).catch(() => caches.match(OFFLINE_URL))
  );
}

// Other fetch handler code...
```

Comment: That's a good approach but seems to also trigger the offline page on error 403, messing up our login process.

Comment: It shouldn't. fetch() won't reject as long as there's some sort of response returned, even if the response has a non-200 error code. Try running `fetch('https://httpbin.org/status/403').then(response => console.log('resolved', response)).catch(error => console.error('rejected', error));` in the JS console and see what it logs.

Comment: Seems like you're absolutely right, there's something else causing the worker to serve wrong content. I'll need to investigate a bit further but since your solution seems to be the way to go I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: for anybody reading the comments - we are using nginx to proxy a backend (at least on development) so using this approach it was never falling into the catch, i needed to sniff the res code and then manually reject - like so --> https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch

Comment: @JeffPosnick It seems that inside the service worker the `online` and `offline` events never get fired if they are added to `self`. Is that the way it should be or an oversight in Chrome? The `navigator.onLine` property is accessible, however.

Comment: Hey Weston—It's intentional. A service worker isn't running most of the time, and what you're proposing would require effectively "waking it up" each time a device goes online/offline just to fire that event. Events like `fetch` and `message` can wake it up, but that's about it.

Comment: @WestonRuter I don't know much about this but my understanding is that the `sync` event (not supported in all browsers) essentially functions as a "the app came online" event.

Comment: This is triggered on other situations though, e.g a broken TLS certificate (`net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`), and this cannot be detected by the generic error caught which reads `TypeError: Failed to fetch`. Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Keep in mind, that firefox, for example, will return the result of fetch() if it has it cached in the "inApp" cache. So, even though you are offline, your service worker will think you are online...