# How to check if Offline with service worker?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I've been following this tutorial https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/offline/#7

So far I was able to make my service worker cache the offline page and load it but I want to show this offline.html page only when there is no internet access. And the way it works now is it shows it every time I refresh the page even with internet access unless I check the `Bypass for network` checkbox in Chrome's Application tab in the developer tools.

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    console.log(event.request.url);
    event.respondWith(
        fetch('https://mysite/offline.html')
    );;
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best practices for detecting offline state in a service worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46036897/best-practices-for-detecting-offline-state-in-a-service-worker)

Answer (score 7):

You can make use of the `navigator.onLine`. It returns `true` for online and `false` otherwise.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var status = document.getElementById("status");

  function updateOnlineStatus(event) {
    var condition = navigator.onLine ? "online" : "offline";

    status.className = condition;
    status.innerHTML = condition.toUpperCase();
  }
  window.addEventListener('online',  updateOnlineStatus);
  window.addEventListener('offline', updateOnlineStatus);
});
```

```css
#status {
  width: 100%;
  font: bold 1em sans-serif;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.online {
  background: green;
}

.offline {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="status" class="online"> ONLINE </div>
<p> Toggle your network connection to see the effect </p>
```

[Read more on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/Online_and_offline_events)

Answer (score 3):

you can use **navigator.onLine** which will return true or false according to the network connectivity, you can take a look at it [Best practices for detecting offline state in a service worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46036897/best-practices-for-detecting-offline-state-in-a-service-worker) might help.

Comment: `navigator.onLine` returns `true` if it's connected to a network (e.g. wifi), event if the network itself is not connected to the internet.