# Progressive Web App on iOS 12.2 stuck in offline page

Tags: ios, progressive-web-apps

I installed a custom progressive web app via safari and its "Add to Home Screen" option.

If I navigate to a specific page without an internet connection I get the native offline page of safari, as expected. The page shows the following message:

> Safari cannot open the page because your iPhone is not connected to the Internet.

If I turn the internet connection on again, the PWA still shows the native safari offline page, giving the user no possibility to reload the page or navigate to another page.

To put in a nutshell, if I access my PWA without an internet connection once, the PWA shows native offline page of safari forever.

Is this the expected behavior of progressive web applications on iOS 12.2?

My service worker looks like this:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', (evt) => {
    return;
});
```

Even if I serve a custom offline page as described in this [article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/), the PWA is still stuck on the offline page, if I turn on my internet connection again.

Comment: I noted the exact same behaviour with an iOS PWA I have been testing. It still displayed the message even if I force closed it and opened it again. It did however function if I restarted the iPhone XS Max. Have you lodged a bug report?

Comment: I submitted the following (using some of your words) to the Apple iPhone Feedback page: “If I access my PWA without internet connection once, the PWA shows the native offline page of Safari forever (or until I restart the iPhone).”

Comment: @user1946932 thanks for your assistance. Is it possible to post a public link to the bug report? As a workaround i'm working on a cached custom offline page, which includes buttons to reload the page or navigate to another url. I'm going to post a guide here, if it works out well. Anyways, i'm curious to see if this is a actual bug, which would render many progressive web applications (without a custom caching strategy and offline page) useless, if you access them offline once.

Comment: I just submitted it at apple.com/feedback/iphone.html. We’d be interested to see your guide too if it all works out.

Comment: Did you have any success so far with a workaround?

Comment: Does the accepted answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46036897/best-practices-for-detecting-offline-state-in-a-service-worker?rq=1 help?

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: Implementing a custom offline page as described [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/) with a button to reload the page or antoher url within your PWA, should work. I  haven't validated it yet. But I am going to post the resulting behavior as soon as i tried the suggested solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the expected behaviour when there is no default offline fallback page. Instead, I'd recommend creating a proper offline fallback page. There's a complete sample you can copy/paste in [Create an offline fallback page](https://web.dev/offline-fallback-page/).

It includes the [service worker code](https://web.dev/offline-fallback-page/#the-service-worker-code) you need, and a [basic offline page](https://web.dev/offline-fallback-page/#the-offline-fallback-page) that will attempt to reload the page once the network or server is back. You can see a working demo at https://basic-pwa.glitch.me/