# Making Service Worker always load files from server, unless Offline

Tags: javascript, service-worker, offline-caching

As I understand, Service Workers have their own cache. And HTTP traffic has a separate cache.

When you are offline, a browser refuses to show you a website from a HTTP cache, but it gladly shows you a website from a Service Worker cache.

I update my website many times a day (only the content of files, URLs remain the same). My HTTP caching is set to one hour.

I want to offer an offline mode. But when online, a website should always be loaded from a server (or from 1-hour HTTP cache).

What code should I use for such Service Worker? I believe it is not described here: https://web.dev/offline-cookbook

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46036897/best-practices-for-detecting-offline-state-in-a-service-worker

Answer (score 2):

Based on your use case I would say you can go with `"Network first"` approach.

```
self.addEventListener(’fetch’, function (event) {
    event.respondWith(
        fetch(event.request).catch(function() {
            return caches.match(event.request)
        })
    )
})
```

In your fetch event handler we are doing following things:-

- Use the `fetch` method to get data from the server.
- Add a `catch` handler in case of network failure and get data from the cache storage.(which will in case of `offline` state).

Note:- We are assuming you are caching data in your `install` event of service worker.
if you are not then we can do that in `fetch` event also.

Comment: That is great, thanks! Can I cache files in "fetch" instead of "install"? I had caching inside "install" for an hour yesterday, and now, there are several thousands of people stuck with an old version of my webapp, who knows for how long :(  https://github.com/photopea/photopea/issues/3450

Comment: Please share your `service-worker` code how you are caching the response in `install ` event.

Comment: Hi, I made a demo service worker here: https://www.photopea.com/sw_new.js , will it do what I want? As there are thousands of different files, I would like to cache only those in "list", how can I do it?

Comment: If you have predefined files list then catch those in `install` event.

Comment: When you open a website, eight files are loaded. If you press a specific button, eight more files are loaded. Only 20% of users need all 16 files, so I dont want to make everyone download all 16 when website is opened (so I can not use "install" event).

Comment: What exactly is your requirement? I am guessing there are many use cases which you are trying to achieve in service worker.  I would suggest target to address one problem statement at 1 time will be useful.

Comment: The whole point of service worker is make app loading faster(using cache) which will lead to less load on servers.

Comment: I want everybody to use the latest version (i.e. no caching), and load fast (8 basic files, the other 8 files load only if the user needs them). But I want the offline functionality for 0.0001% of users (in that case, the last opened version should be displayed to them, at least 8 basic files).

Comment: For fast loading you have to serve from caching and they can still use the latest version. How often data changes in server?

Comment: Data is changed 1x to 10x a day.

Comment: I am taking about the static files not API response.

Comment: Yes, I change static files 1x to 10x a day. It is my only job to develop my website.

Comment: In that case, every time your deploy your application update your service worker.js file content. You can do it in your CI workflow as well.

Comment: Why? You want me to use new file names for new JS files?

Comment: Nop, only the service-worker.js file content. As per SW docs. if there is any changes in SW file content then it considered it as new service worker and hence all the life-cycle events will come into picture including install event and in that case you update your cache as it will fetch the resource from server.

Comment: As I said, the cache of a service worker should only be used when offline. So is my sw.js correct? https://photopea.com/sw_new.js

Comment: In that case above code which I mentioned in the answer will work. However you still need to update the cache with latest version so that while offline user get the latest version.