# Reusable hook for checking internet connection in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For my sample application I was trying to check whether internet connection is there or not, I was using a reusable hook for this as shown below:

```
function useNetwork() {
    const [isOnline, setNetwork] = useState(window.navigator.onLine);
    const updateNetwork = () => {
        setNetwork(window.navigator.onLine);
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("offline", updateNetwork);
        window.addEventListener("online", updateNetwork);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("offline", updateNetwork);
            window.removeEventListener("online", updateNetwork);
        };
    });
    return isOnline;
}
```

The problem is it's working in Chrome, but when I checked in Safari when I tried turning off the wifi still **isOnline** returns true, I tried in the console of safari also, as window.navigator.isOnline it returns true.

Reading through different questions, [here **Danilo**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283124/navigator-online-not-always-working) recommends to send a httpRequest and check it.

So should I send a get request to any site like google.com so I can know the status and set my onLine value as true. Because I think I need to poll this, since the above hook takes care when the dom is changed.

How can I achieve this, or is there any better way? How can I implement this in the above reusable hook.

Comment: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/11290

Comment: Thanks Dilshan for the response ,i have gone through this also, since i am not using any vmware or any box just normal wifi.  I was able to achieve most of the cases but through safari its not properly working.

Comment: I think its better send a network request to a live server to check connection. Here's an Angular service which is use to check internet status. This will help to get an idea - https://github.com/ultrasonicsoft/ng-connection-service/blob/master/projects/connection-service/src/lib/connection-service.service.ts

Comment: @Dilshan thanks for the info, but this also internally checks against the internethealthtest.org site with time Interval, In most of the questions related to this from the mdn it was mentioned both chrome and safari will have the issue, but for me only safari gives the issue. chrome is working fine

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this,and have an api end point/or call any reliable api

```js
const useNetworkStatus = () => {
    const [isOnline, setStatus] = useState();
    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            try {
                window.networkPoll = setInterval(async () => {
                    const networkStatus = await fetch(/*your api*/);
                    if (networkStatus.code != 200) {
                        setStatus(false);
                    }
                    if (networkStatus.code == 200) {
                        setStatus(true);
                    }

                }, 5000);
            }
            catch (error) {
                setStatus(false);
            }
        })();
    }, []);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the response , the problem is since if i use polling every 5 seconds i need to call this, is there any way without using polling, because if the actual api is down and the internet connection is active then that will be a wrong case isn't.  Thats why i was using window change so it wont use any polling