# Why is navigator.onLine true while I have wifi switched off?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, wifi, navigator

I have the following code on my page:

```
const offlineMessage = document.querySelector('.show-offline-only');

window.addEventListener('online',  updateIndicator);
window.addEventListener('offline', updateIndicator);
updateIndicator();

function updateIndicator() {
  offlineMessage.style.display = navigator.onLine ? 'none' : 'block';
}
```

When I use the Chrome developers tools to switch from online to offline and back, this works like a charm. However, when I actually switch off my Wifi or go to airplane mode, nothing happens.

Can anyone explain to me why this is the case and how to solve this behavior?

**Edit:** From the comments I get that, apparently, navigator.onLine is not working. Does this also mean that there is no way to listen to a change in my network connectivity and I have to run a loop on my page to check every few seconds, or so, whether or not I am still online / have gone offline / have gone back online?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation of `navigator.onLine`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine)?

Comment: Duplicate of [navigator.onLine not always working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283124/navigator-online-not-always-working).

Comment: Okay, so Navigator.online is not really reliable and I should use another trick to check whether or not I am online. However, in that case, how can I listen to a change in online/offline status?