# How can I listen to my online/offline status?

Tags: javascript, wifi, event-listener

Is there a way to listen to the online/offline status? I have tried using

```
window.addEventListener('online',  function);
```

However, this doesn't seem to work in Chrome (see also: [Why is navigator.onLine true while I have wifi switched off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63112547/why-is-navigator-online-true-while-i-have-wifi-switched-off))

To be clear: I am not just interested in assessing whether or not I am online, I want to listen to changes in the online/offline status.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [navigator.onLine not always working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283124/navigator-online-not-always-working)

Comment: Using the answers in the question above you could poll a known location and if it fails emit an event?

Comment: I don't like polling... That way I would create unnecessary traffic. So, unfortunately it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Then the answer is probably “no, you can’t”. — EDIT: ooo maybe you could us service workers? I’m not sure how it could communicate with the page though

Comment: @MWB any success? Even I don't want to add polling or interval to keep checking.

Comment: Unfortunately, no